# Getting 64-bit CPUID sample code to compile in VS2008

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, assembly

I'm trying to get some c & ASM sample code I found running in Visual Studio 2008.  I don't think the problem is the difference between VS 2005-2008.  [This example](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cpuid-for-x64-platforms-and-microsoft-visual-studio-net-2005/) is supposed to get the CPUID on 64-bit systems.  (My attempts getting the ASM-only 32-bit examples to compile failed too)

I can copy and paste this code into a new project, but I have not been able to build it.  I've tried a few different VS project templates with no success.  I believe I followed the instructions all the way.  Can someone provide a step-by-step to get this running in Visual Studio 2008 with the project template and project settings?

One thing I've noticed is that although I can make the environment be 64-bit, I can't seem to target x64 for this project - the only options for adding new platforms are mobile platforms.  And I've had to manually define _M_X64 in the command-line options, which I suspect I shouldn't have to do.

Not to be debugged directly, but just for your info - Errors, as far as I got, are as follows:

```
1> Assembling: .\cpuid64.asm
1>.\cpuid64.asm(4) : error A2013:.MODEL must precede this directive
1>.\cpuid64.asm(5) : error A2034:must be in segment block
1>.\cpuid64.asm(7) : error A2034:must be in segment block : cpuid64
1>.\cpuid64.asm(11) : error A2034:must be in segment block
1>.\cpuid64.asm(12) : error A2008:syntax error : .
1>.\cpuid64.asm(13) : error A2034:must be in segment block
1>.\cpuid64.asm(14) : error A2008:syntax error : .
1>.\cpuid64.asm(15) : error A2008:syntax error : .
1>.\cpuid64.asm(17) : error A2034:must be in segment block
1>.\cpuid64.asm(18) : error A2085:instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode
1>.\cpuid64.asm(19) : error A2085:instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode
1>.\cpuid64.asm(20) : error A2085:instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode
1>.\cpuid64.asm(21) : error A2085:instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode
1>.\cpuid64.asm(22) : error A2085:instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode
1>.\cpuid64.asm(23) : error A2085:instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode
1>.\cpuid64.asm(24) : error A2085:instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode
1>.\cpuid64.asm(26) : error A2034:must be in segment block
1>.\cpuid64.asm(27) : error A2034:must be in segment block
1>.\cpuid64.asm(29) : error A2034:must be in segment block
1>.\cpuid64.asm(30) : error A2034:must be in segment block
1>.\cpuid64.asm(31) : fatal error A1010:unmatched block nesting : cpuid64
```

Comment: I just posted a related question, but not exactly the same as this (different approach)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216535/x86-x64-cpuid-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you can't target `x64`, you have a slight problem because you're not using the `x64` toolchain. I strongly suggest you use the VS install wizard to add in the `x64` tools. You should be able to go to new platform, call it `x64` and base it on `win32`.

Having said that, I actually recommend using [YASM](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/wiki/Download) because it allows you to integrate with VS, and YASM is by far a nicer assembler than Microsoft's.

Since I happen to have a project that would benefit from this anyway, I thought I'd do it using yasm:

**gcpuid.asm**:

```
; CPUID on x64-Win32
; Ref: 

section .code
global gcpuid

; void cpuid(uint32_t* cpuinfo, char* vendorstr);

gcpuid:

    push rbp
    mov  rbp, rsp

    mov  r8, rcx   ; capture the first and second arguments into 1-> r8, 2-> r9
    mov  r9, rdx   ; cause cpuid will obliterate the lower half of those regs

    ; retrive the vendor string in its
    ; three parts
    mov eax, 0
    cpuid
    mov [r9+0], ebx    
    mov [r9+4], edx
    mov [r9+8], ecx

    ; retrieve the cpu bit string that tells us
    ; all sorts of juicy things
    mov eax, 1
    cpuid
    mov [r8], eax
    mov eax, 0

    leave
    ret
```

**cpuid-w32.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void gcpuid(uint32_t* cpuinfo, char* vendorstr);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char vendor[13] = { 0 };
    uint32_t flags;

    gcpuid(&flags, vendor);
    printf("Flags: %u, Vendor: %s\n", flags, vendor);

    return 0;
}
```

Following **readme.txt** in the vs2010 archive supplied on the links download page, it was a doddle to get vs to assemble this, and this solution is much clearer, I think, than intels.

As to what you *do* with the cpuinfo parameter, well, you can try various masks to find out all sorts of info about the cpu type. I might update if I finish the implementation.

Comment: I have not had a chance to verify this answer, but I appreciate the effort you put into answering it.  I'll award you the points.

Comment: @JasonKleban Can you help me to get cpu **id** using this code? Not flags or vendor.

Comment: @JasonKleban I have found intel manual [link](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/IA_32_Instructions_2A.pdf) see 25th page, it is about cpuid syntax. But it is unreadable...