# How to load a Win32 executable file and run it from memory?

Tags: c#, winapi, memory

In case i have an executable embedded as a resource in a process and would like to run the process directly from memory without having it on disk.

```
static void Main()
{
const string pathOfExecutable = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"; //size = 67KB 
// read the bytes from the application EXE file
FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathOfExecutable, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] byteArray = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
br.Close();


//Process.Start(byteArray) //Cannot use this, any other alternative?

}
```

Comment: You're trying to load notepad.exe as a CLR assembly. Notepad is not a .NET app, thus the BadImageFormatException.
The solution you linked to only works for CLR executables.

Comment: Down-voters please explain you rationale for down voting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory-using-c-sharp

Comment: My guess for downvotes would be a lack of a full explanation as to what you are trying to achieve ("described here" doesn't count), seems a little harsh though

Comment: On an unrelated note; empty catch statements are the devil's play things. I'm a java man so my terminology may be off but consider throwing a runtime exception at least

Comment: Question edited as per comments

Answer (score 2):

`Assembly.Load` will load .net assemblies. Notepad is not such a thing. It's a plain old native Win32 application. What you are attempting to do cannot be done with `Assembly.Load`.

Comment: Any ideas on how to load a win32 app from memory?

Comment: It's not supported. There are many examples of hacking it. You just need to do a websearch to find them.

Comment: Write the executable contents out to a temporary location then execute it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach works only with managed executables. notepad.exe is a native executable. To run it, use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

Comment: Tried Process.start()

Comment: @kol The comment I was replying to was deleted.

Comment: @ta.speot.is OK. Thanks, I thought there is a problem with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to write the memory content to a temporary file (`Path.GetTempFileName`), then run it with `Process.Start()`

Comment: -1 *"run the process directly from memory without having it on disk"*

Comment: @IInspectable You're quoting from an edit made after this answer. At any rate, it's not possible to start an arbitrary Win32 application from memory. This answer is the next best thing.

Comment: @ta It is not impossible, just a complex task. The OS does not directly support executing a native binary PE image from memory, however, if you look at a running process have precisely this scenario (ignoring memory mapping of the backing store for argument's sake). A detailed approach is outlined at [Loading a DLL from memory](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/).

Comment: Not possible to do in any supported fashion.

Comment: @ta It is very much supported for kernel modules.

Comment: The question is not about kernel modules.