# Load msi file to the memory and install it from memory?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

Is it a possible to Load msi file to the memory and install it from memory? 
The client download the msi file from server. Firstly the client get the byte array. And then save it as a msi file. and then install it. But I always think it is a possible if client get the byte array and then install it . Don't need to save it in the local drive and install it? If yes, could you give me a C# sample?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Why? What is the use case to do this?

Comment: Yes it is possible but why you want to execute from memory? If you have the whole downloaded file in memory you might think again in your design. Keeping a large file in memory just to execute it!?

Comment: Are you trying to update your program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load an EXE file and run it from memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory)