# Visual basic start process from stream

Tags: vb.net

Now for starting process i write bytes to file and start process from storage.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(fullFileName, data, True)
Process.Start(fullFileName)
```

how to start process from stream?

Comment: You can load an assembly in the current process without the assembly existing on disk. However for a process you need a executable on disk (or network drive) to get things started.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3553911/2319909