# C# run a C++ EXE from memory

Tags: c#, c++, .net, memory, execute

The basic code is here: [Load an EXE file and run it from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory)

If I load the binary like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFilename, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
br.Close();
```

the run function works fine. If I load the file with the above code and delete the sFilename after this, the code exits at

```
if (!UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateProcess(sFilename/*null*/, hostProcess, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, UnsafeNativeMethods.CREATE_SUSPENDED, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref StartupInfo, PROCESS_INFO))
```

Has any body an idea, why the CreateProcess doesn't work without existing sFilename in the filesystem?