# Run in-memory binary executable from bytes object

Tags: python

How to run an executable file (`.exe`), which will be the program code, from memory without saving to disk?

1. I have an `.exe` file stored as bytes. It was obtained
   using `open('1.exe', 'rb').read()`.
2. I put the byte literal in the Python code of a script: `byteCode = b'\x00\x00\x00\...'`.
3. Now I need to run this executable. But from memory, without saving to disk.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. You need to be specific and ask a clear question. Do you want to run `.exe` file with python?

Comment: It seems Op has the binary contents of an executable and wishes to run it without saving to disk first.

Comment: Based on [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory) it dosen't appear to be very easy. Writing to a temporary directory and running it from there seems easiest.

Comment: Is it a Win32 exe? What OS are you using/targeting? Why do you have to execute it from memory not disc? Why not just run `1.exe`?

Comment: @wjandrea, yes it is Win32 exe. I am use Windows.