# Is there a way to secure EXE file?

Tags: security, memory, exe, file-security, locked-files

I have an application that use EXE file in it.
I want to secure EXE file, I encrypt file but it should be decrypted to use in the program, so I have to create temporary EXE file in to hard disk.

my questions are:

1) How can I create it in memory that no one can access to it? (EXE file uses commands to run)

2) How can I run this file from locked folder without unlocking folder?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory) question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to change its permissions such that only administrators can access the file.

Then run the program as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Use VeraCrypt (or another TrueCrypt clone). Create an image and put the file into it. It will be encrypted this way. If you want to use it, mount it as a drive and run the exe file inside.