# C++ run .exe from Resource Files

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run exe from Resource Files.

[image: ++]

I used this code but it didn't work.

```
CString str = Path::GetTempPath() + L"proxy.exe";;
CString action = "open";
ShellExecute(NULL, action, str, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: You need to extract the file to disk to run it with ShellExecute. With that said there are some software you can find to run an exe from memory.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory)