# Run EXE file which is loaded to memory with python

Tags: python

I have written a simple Lossless compression algorithm in order to learn a little about compressions and how it is work and in order to check my algorithm I open a exe file read it to variable do the mathematical operation on it run the reverse mathematical operation and run it. (I saved the file and try to run it with `subprocess.popen`

This lead me to think if I have the uncorrupted EXE file in python variable can I run it directly from memory without save it to disk?

for example like this:

```
import example_run_exe_file_from_variable

a_file = open("example.exe", "rb")
full_file = a_file.read()
a_file.close()
.
.
.
.
example_run_exe_file_from_variable.run(full_file)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load an EXE file and run it from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory)

Comment: Basically ^, but using Win32 API from Python via Ctypes, Cython or alternatives.

Comment: @PeterBadida that is a `c#` question, not a good duplicate target for this python question IMO

Comment: @PranavHosangadi as Python doesn't target using binaries this way with its standard library, it's a generic question with an application for C# like this is for Python and both end up in using Win32 API just in a different wrapping mechanism - which is the reasoning for the duplicate vote. Therefore OP might just end up with rewriting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233591/5994041) or similar approach with Ctypes/Cython. Same like other linked questions to the duplicate candidate.