# How can I load a byte array into memory and run it as an executable?

Tags: c#, wpf

Nothing malicious here.. it is for a trial licensing design. The main application decrypts the target .exe file, loads it into memory and executes it, starting the program, (if the licence key is valid). I know this can be done, it's how Cnet used to handle shareware.. but can it be done in C# with whatever user permissions are available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running executable from memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277711/running-executable-from-memory) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553875/load-an-exe-file-and-run-it-from-memory-using-c-sharp

Comment: This kind of DRM is like the lock on your front door -- it'll keep an honest person honest, but isn't secure and if someone wants to break in they will. Don't make something so complicated. Think simpler.

Comment: Well.. it bypasses the need for obfuscation (which I like).. still thinking about it, best approaches.. I was hoping Cnet still did the whole 'end to end' thing, looks like that's gone now.. so I have to write my own ;o(

Comment: This particular question asked many times and have many answers - please check existing ones. On second half - there is nothing preventing local (full trust) C#/.Net application to do what native application does - so if you know what native approach you want to replicate - go ahead and do that, you may need plenty of PInvoke and interop... But http://pinvoke.net will likely solve most of the issues. If your question is about something else - clarify or ask new one (linking to existing once with one line explanation why it is not enough).