# Access CPUIDs (cpu serial numbers) WITHOUT using WMI using VB.net or C#

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, wmi, unmanaged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [x86/x64 CPUID in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216535/x86-x64-cpuid-in-c)

I need to retrieve CPU's serial numbers. When using WMI, it is called CPUID.
My goal is to access that information **WITHOUT** using WMI.

Unmanaged is code is fine

```
I really need some sample code and preferably .NET implementation
```

Comment: Why did you tag C++ if you want to use VB.net or C#?

Comment: that will be the last resort option:)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a CPU's CPUID with the `__cpuid()` function from `<intrin.h>`. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: do you have sample code? And possibly .NET implementation? That's what I am looking for