# Getting CPU or GPU ID on Mono (C#)

Tags: c#, mono

I'm trying to get the CPU or GPU ID in C# using Mono 2.0. System.Management would be great, but Mono doesn't support It yet, so It fails. Any ideas how could I do It by using C++ natives or something?

Comment: Is allocating executable memory and running some x86 or x64 assembly code in it like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216535/x86-x64-cpuid-in-c-sharp an option?

Comment: I think so. I will see If I works.